# React - Spread MapStateToProps with the same props

Tags: javascript, reactjs, spread-syntax

I have this MapStateToProps:

```
const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  const date = new Date();
  const year = date.getFullYear();
  const month = date.getMonth() + 1;

  const ESFReport = getESFReport(state);
  const resultStatusReport = getResultStatusReport(state);

  return {
    companInfo: getCompanyInfo(state),
    companyId: getCompanyId(state),
    ...ESFReport,
    ...resultStatusReport,
    year,
    month,
  };
};
```

And both `...ESFReport,` and `...resultStatusReport`, have the same property: `report` but I need somehow to change the name because in the same component I use `const { report } = this.props` two times but for different props.

How can I do this? (it used to work when I have only ...ESFReport, but when I added ...resultStatusReport, it broke).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: do you need anything other than `report` on `ESFReport` and `resultStatusReport`?

Comment: yes @Tony `report` is an array of objects that has the keys report, error, year and month and I need to access to everything inside `report`

Comment: Sorry, no, report is the only thing I need from both of them, and inside report is everything I need

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't need anything other than `report` from the `ESFReport` and `resultStatusReport` objects you could do:

```
const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  const date = new Date();
  const year = date.getFullYear();
  const month = date.getMonth() + 1;

  const { report: ESFReport } = getESFReport(state);
  const { report: resultStatusReport } = getResultStatusReport(state);

  return {
    companInfo: getCompanyInfo(state),
    companyId: getCompanyId(state),
    ESFReport,
    resultStatusReport,
    year,
    month,
  };
};
```

It just renames the `report` property on each to `ESFReport` and `resultStatusReport`. You would then have `this.props.ESFReport` which would actually be  `ESFReport.report` and `this.props.resultStatusReport` which would be `resultStatusReport.report`.